# Angular 5: $any is not a function

Tags: angular

I have problem in Angular 5. I get this error in Chrome Dev Tools, in different projects. I am using VS Code. Doing 'npm install' locally for each folder.

> ERROR TypeError: jit_nodeValue_6(...).$any is not a function

For example I have this html page, filter won't work on HTML:

```html
<h3>List Component</h3>

<h4>Selected Person: {{selectedPerson}}</h4>
Filter: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]=by>

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let person of personList | filter:by">
        <a href="http://www.google.com" (click)=select($event,person)>{{person}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string[], args = ""): any {
        return value.filter(item => item.startsWith(args));
    }
}
```

This should filter person from person list, and display only matching persons on UI.

EDIT: package.json is

```js
{
  "name": "helloapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Hello App in Angular 5",
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config ./webpack-config/webpack.prod.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "2.5.3",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.17",
    "@types/node": "^8.5.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.4.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "typescript": "2.5.3",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: try removing `:any`

Comment: Start by reading https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe. Now regarding your issue, it's not related to your code. Probably to the configuration of your project. Post the package.json file.

Comment: I copy/pasted your code in local and it works fine. Could could provide more informations as your package.json.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, I also think it is related to configuration as at one point everything was working, then stopped.

Comment: @phpdroid no, that haven't helped

Comment: What happens when you replace `^5.1.2` by `5.1.2`? You want all the angular modules to have the exact same version number. I also strongly recomment to use the CLI.

Comment: @JBNizet I did that, than cleared npm cache, and now I have this problem with npm can't find some files/directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that error was in package.json.
I recreated it like this, and now it works. Any comment or explanation what was wrong is very welcome.

```js
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Hello World in Angular",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config ./webpack-config/webpack.prod.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "2.5.3",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "0.8.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.18",
    "@types/node": "^9.3.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.4.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "typescript": "2.5.3",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be ever so helpful if you could depict the changed lines?